# Docusign List data from dynamic JSON array containing objects

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to get the Docusign template to display dynamic data like list items for a quote however I cannot seem to find the right solution since a text tab is either displaying nothing or displays the last item in the array.

Here is a dummy array that represents what I want to display: [{"name":"John", "age":10}, {"name":"Doe", "age":10}]. Imagine that these details are completely dynamic and the length of the array is also unknown before hand.

I am using the nodejs library. "docusign-esign": "^6.3.0",

This is the code that I got from the documentation:

```
function createTabs(){
let list1 = docusign.List.constructFromObject({
  value: "green",
  documentId: "1",
  pageNumber: "1",
  tabLabel: "list",
});

// Checkboxes
let check1 = docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
    tabLabel: "ckAuthorization",
    selected: "true",
  }),
  check3 = docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
    tabLabel: "ckAgreement",
    selected: "true",
  });
// The NOde.js SDK has a bug so it cannot create a Number tab at this time.
//number1 = docusign.Number.constructFromObject({
//    tabLabel: "numbersOnly", value: '54321'});
let radioGroup = docusign.RadioGroup.constructFromObject({
  groupName: "radio1",
  // You only need to provide the radio entry for the entry you're selecting
  radios: [
    docusign.Radio.constructFromObject({ value: "white", selected: "true" }),
  ],
});
let text = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
  tabLabel: "text",
  value: "Jabberwocky!",
});

// We can also add a new tab (field) to the ones already in the template:
let textExtra = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
  document_id: "1",
  page_number: "1",
  x_position: "280",
  y_position: "172",
  font: "helvetica",
  font_size: "size14",
  tab_label: "added text field",
  height: "23",
  width: "84",
  required: "false",
  bold: "true",
  value: args.signerName,
  locked: "false",
  tab_id: "name",
});

// Pull together the existing and new tabs in a Tabs object:
let tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
  checkboxTabs: [check1, check3], // numberTabs: [number1],
  radioGroupTabs: [radioGroup],
  textTabs: [text, textExtra],
  listTabs: [list1],
});
// Create the template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
// to the template
let signer = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
  email: args.signerEmail,
  name: args.signerName,
  roleName: "signer",
  clientUserId: args.signerClientId, // change the signer to be embedded
  tabs: tabs, // Set tab values
});
// Create a cc template role.
let cc = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
  email: args.ccEmail,
  name: args.ccName,
  roleName: "cc",
});
// Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
envelopeDefinition.templateRoles = [signer, cc];
// Create an envelope custom field to save the our application's
// data about the envelope
let customField = docusign.TextCustomField.constructFromObject({
    name: "app metadata item",
    required: "false",
    show: "true", // Yes, include in the CoC
    value: "1234567",
  }),
  customFields = docusign.CustomFields.constructFromObject({
    textCustomFields: [customField],
  });
envelopeDefinition.customFields = customFields;

return envelopeDefinition;
}
```

Using text tabs only displays the last item in the array and the list tab does not seem to have a corresponding element in the template design UI on docusign.

Here is my own code that I adapted from the above code:

```
let list1 = docusign.List.constructFromObject({value: JSON.stringify(quoteDetails),tabLabel:"quote_details",})

let projectNameText = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
 value: projectName,
      tabLabel: "project_name",
      bold: "true",
    });
    let docusignTextTabs = [...quoteDetailDocusignObjects, projectNameText]
    console.log(docusignTextTabs)
    let tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
      textTabs: docusignTextTabs,
      listTabs: [list1],
      dateSignedTabs: [{ tabLabel: "date_signed" }],
    });
    let signer1 = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
      email: email,
      name: name,
      clientUserId: email,
      roleName: "Customer",
      tabs: tabs,
    });
```

I tried using the List tab but it would not display anything on the template. There is also no "List" option on the docusign template dashboard

Comment: In your real code, not this dummy code, do you have the same value for tabLabel in all tabs in the array?